# Does Apache spark supports persisting dataframe (data) in teradata?

Tags: apache-spark, teradata, apache-spark-sql

I need to persist data in teradata and I am using spark to achieve this using jdbc connection.

But whenever I try to persist dataframe in teradata, each time spark try to create a new table inspite of using any SaveMode and the table creation operation gets failed.

I dug down then found that spark checks if the table exist or not using below statement

`Try(conn.prepareStatement(s"SELECT 1 FROM $table LIMIT 1") .executeQuery().next()).isSuccess`

This `Limit` keyword is not supported in Teradata so it gives the error and spark considers it as the table not present and try to create new table for each dataframe write operation.

Any workaround for this or any other way to persist dataframe in teradata?

Comment: For teradata, the appropriate syntax would be `select top 1 1 from <your table>`.  That will basically return a 1 if the table exists and has at least one row.

Comment: @Andrew, yes you are absolutely right about the syntax but the query that I mentioned in the question is generated by spark internally.